# Keyboard stays lit during sleep

Tags: keyboard, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

When I put my computer to sleep the keyboard stays lit. It is a July 2012 rMBP. I always have to turn down the brightness manually which is really annoying. Does someone know how to fix this?

Also when I try to turn down the brightness the symbol at first indicates that the keyboard illumination is already at zero, so I have to turn it up at first before I can turn it down.

Comment: Have you considered resetting the SMC on the Air to see if the system controller is stuck or not reading a sensor properly?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an SMC reset. You can find the instructions on how to do so here: [SMC Reset (Apple.com)](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964)

Tell me if it works.